# Auto scroll to each div pause and then move on continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create function to scroll to each div with "class=res-" pause and then move onto the next div pause and so on - once it gets to the last div it will restart at the top and continuously do this function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!--*class "res-<some number>" is dynamic so it will never have a static "some number"-->
<div class="main_window">
  <div class="res-1">
    scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to res-2
  </div>

  <div class="res-2">
    scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to res-8-5
  </div>

  <div class="res-8-5">
    scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to top and repeat 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you a bit? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Hi there! For best results, please attempt to write the code yourself and post that. We can then help you discover what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using JavaScript [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

**Note that** the options of `.scrollIntoView()` [doesn't have too good cross-browser support.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)

**Also note that** this will try to scroll your element relative to the window, rather than its parent.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=res-]');
let active = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
  if( ++active >= elements.length) active = 0;
  
  //poor support for options
  elements[active].scrollIntoView({
    behavior:'smooth',
    block:'start' //Where to align current item: 'start', 'end' or 'center'
  })
},5000)
```

```css
[class^=res-]{
  /* huge margin to see scrolling effect*/
  margin-bottom:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_window">
  <div class="res-1">
    scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to res-2
  </div>

  <div class="res-2">
    scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to res-8-5
  </div>

  <div class="res-8-5">
    scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to top and repeat 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via `jQuery` also.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selector = "div[class^='res-']";
    var firstSelect = $("div[class^='res-']:first");
    var lastSelect = $("div[class^='res-']:last");

    $(firstSelect).addClass('active');

    setInterval(function() {
        var next = $(".main_window .active") .removeClass('active').next(selector);

        if (!next.length) next = next.prevObject.siblings(':first');
    
        next.addClass('active');

        $section = $('.active');

        scroll();
    }, 5000);

});

function scroll() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($section.offset().top)},300);    
}
```

```css
div[class^='res-'] {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_window">
    <div class="res-1">scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to res-2
    </div>
    <div class="res-2">scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to res-8-5
    </div>
    <div class="res-8-5">scroll to me then pause for 5 seconds next move to top and repeat
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check it's Output here - https://jsfiddle.net/ydeepak1/jord3spu/11/

Comment: Awesome thank you - I was almost on the same track but I couldn't figure out how to repeat it. @Dipak